# How can I filter for multiple values in AngularJS using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The sales_Use_Taxable field in the database can be one of three options, which are: "Yes", "No", or it can also be null.  Using the below code to filter the results, it does not display the rows that have null for this field.

```
<tr ng-repeat="h in vm.filteredRequisitions = (vm.headers | filter: { por_Detail: { sales_Use_Taxable: vm.tax || '' } }) ...>
```

I believe the important part of this code is `sales_Use_Taxable: vm.tax || ''`.  How can I edit this line to include the rows that have null for the sales_Use_Taxable field?

Comment: please headers array as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result , change empty quotes '' to **undefined**  which will return all rows including null values

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  //$scope.tax = 'YES'
  $scope.headers = [
    {"por_Detail" : {
       "sales_Use_Taxable" : null
    } },
    {"por_Detail" : {
       "sales_Use_Taxable" : 'YES'
    } },
    {"por_Detail" : {
       "sales_Use_Taxable" : 'NO'
    } }
  ]
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="h in headers | filter: { por_Detail: { sales_Use_Taxable: tax || undefined} }">
  <td>{{h}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>



</body>
</html>
```

codepen for reference with example - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WLPrPj